# XMLDB Ошибка "failed No such file or directory" при импорте из файла в таблицу

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

Надо импортировать XML файл в Oracle XMLDB.
Вроде делаю все по правилам:

1. ```
   CREATE TABLE orders OF XMLTYPE
   ```
2. ```
   CREATE DIRECTORY TT AS '/home/oracle/Desktop/contract_test/'(GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY TT TO superuser;)`
   ```
3. ```
   INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES (xmltype(bfilename('TT', 'contract.xml'), nls_charset_id('utf-8')));
   ```

На выходе получаю эту ошибку:

> Error starting at line : 1 in command - INSERT INTO ORDERS VALUES
>   (xmltype(bfilename('TT', 'contract.xml'), nls_charset_id('utf-8')))
>   Error report - SQL Error: ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN
>   failed No such file or directory
>   22288. 00000 -  "file or LOB operation %s failed\n%s"
>   *Cause:    The operation attempted on the file or LOB failed.
>   *Action:   See the next error message in the error stack for more detailed
>              information.  Also, verify that the file or LOB exists and that
>              the necessary privileges are set for the specified operation. If
>              the error still persists, report the error to the DBA.

Эта ошибка возникает даже, если я делаю под system аккаунтом. Не только под тем, который я сам создал (с полным доступом).

Comment: В п.2 команда выглядит как то странно, по видимому вы ошиблись при копи+паста. Как в сообщении об ошибке сказано, вставка не может найти файл. Добавте вывод команды `ls -la` в указаном каталоге.

Comment: Через консоль проверял путь, смотря на ошибку, ещё до поста. Через консоль все отлично

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для импорта XML данных из файловой системы в таблицу, надо поместить файл в папку, для которой существует объект каталога (*directory object*) в схеме БД. Так же, необходимо дать разрешение на чтение. Прав на чтение на уровне БД недостаточно, нужны также права на уровне файловой системы ОС.

Например, так будет работать:

```
~$ mkdir inbound; cd inbound
~/inbound$ echo "<id>1</id>" >contract.xml

~/inbound$ chmod o+rx .
~/inbound$ chmod o+r contract.xml

~/inbound$ pwd
/home/db/inbound

SQL> create table contracts of xmlType;
Table created.

SQL> create directory xmldoc as '/home/db/inbound';
Directory created.

SQL> insert into contracts values (
         xmlType (bfilename ('XMLDOC', 'contract.xml'), nls_charset_id ('AL32UTF8')));

1 row created.

SQL> select c.object_value.getClobVal () doc from contracts c ;
DOC
--------------------------------
<id>1</id>
```